# How to tell blender to only render Keyframes?

Tags: rendering, keyframes

Is there a way to only render Keyframes and just copy normal Frames to speed up rendering? I ask because there are longer breaks in my animation.

E.g. Timeline

- Frame 1 with Keyframes
- Frame 2 no Keyframes
- Frame 3 no Keyframes
- Frame 4 with Keyframes

The render renders Frame 1, copies Frames 2+3 and renders Frame 4.

Thanks!

Comment: For EEVEE you can use View ⇾ Viewport render keyframes.

Comment: i think you could easily do this with a small python script

Comment: I use CYCLES and there is unfortunately no such entry and with blender python I'm not convinced. But why doesn't ds use Blender by default, doesn't it make sense to render something that hasn't changed or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There's the addon Loom which can be found there:

[p2or/blender-loom: image sequence rendering, encoding and playback](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom)

When installed, you will find a Loom popover in every animation editor's header that allows you to, for example, select some keyframes and render them:

[image: render keyframes]

You can then encode it with the addon's [Encode image sequence dialog](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom#encode-image-sequence-dialog-ctrlshiftf9):

[image: encode image sequence dialog]

Comment: wow...didn't know that. Really useful add-on!!

Comment: Very useful but a bit tricky to use. Hence I don't try explaining myself too much, I will make a mess x)

Comment: That's interesting, but what do I do with the frames to be copied in between, I have about 6000 frames?

Comment: you can then encode it with the addon's [Encode image sequence dialog](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom#encode-image-sequence-dialog-ctrlshiftf9).

Comment: Cheers @L0Lock. Just updated the [documentation and added a few new options](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom#render-specific-keyframes), I hope this helps to eliminate the mess a bit... If you think there is something to improve like a dedicated dialog for layout having both functions in one place or something, I would appreciate your feedback. Just open up a new issue on github so we can discuss about it, all ideas are welcome.